# ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission (this, permission) was not found, which I need so that the method does not send me error

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I call this method to see the checked permissions, it sends me an error, since I do not know if it has a reference and I have not passed it on, and I need to know if anything is needed to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend trying the Permissions Plugin by @jamesmontemagno
[PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)